# Tag Synonym request: [.bashrc] -> [bash]

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

Please could we have the [.bashrc] tag made a synonym of [bash]. Statistics:

- 0 questions ever
- 0 followers ever

It is not needed.

So:

[.bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/.bashrc) -> [bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bash)

Comment: There's no point to that tag, since there's [tag:bashrc]. I nuked it. It will go away in about 4 hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If any action is taken, [.bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/.bashrc) should be made a synonym of [bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bashrc), not of [bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bash).

It's true that we don't need a separate tag [.bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/.bashrc). That tag is *hardly* used (surely *some* question has at some point in its life had that tag, since that's how tags are created).

But the reason we don't need it is that we have [bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bashrc), which is extensively used. Currently it has 408 questions.

A possible, but not very good, argument for keeping a separate [.bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/.bashrc) tag would be that it refers to the `.bashrc` files in people's home directories and `/etc/skel`, and *not* to `/bash/bashrc`. I say this is not a very good argument because:

- We don't currently have questions tagged with it.
- It seems unlikely that this level of granularity would be useful.

I do believe that [bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bashrc) **without the dot** is useful and should continue to exist separately from [bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bash), which is a hugely broader topic. I think neither [.bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/.bashrc) nor [bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bashrc) should be synonymized to [bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bash).

The only reason I can see not to synonymize [.bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/.bashrc) to [bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bashrc) is that *it has no tags, so the system won't let us*.

[image: Tooltip showing the system's refusal to make .bashrc a synonym of bashrc because it does not exist in the system.]

<sup>*"Failed to propose synonym: The suggested tag must exist in the system before suggesting it as a synonym!"*</sup>

I suppose a moderator could do it, but unless the tag comes back (i.e., unless people start tagging questions with it again), this is probably unnecessary.

Comment: "Some question" being https://askubuntu.com/questions/939736/what-is-the-difference-between-etc-profile-and-bashrc in the current iteration.